# HP Envy x360 Laptop- Blender is running slow and crashing and I have no idea how to rectify this

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I've been using Blender on my laptop for about a day now and I got this far in creating the donut, however the software keeps crashing, freezing and not responding. Would you be able to help me rectify this problem as I can not seem to move on from this point. I think I have too many vertices on my icing, that's why I think it is slow.

My laptop - HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-bq1xx

Processor- AMD Ryzen 5 32500U With Radeon Vega  Mobile Gfx 2.00 GHz and 8 GB RAM

Not really good at computers either.

[image]

Comment: When you say too many vertices, how many do you mean? Blender can handle multiple millions on most machines, so that's likely not the case. Are your graphics drivers up to date? Also, what rendering engine are you using, Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: you have 8.4 million vertices, 4 million faces (look in the bottom right of the screen)  using 7.5 GB of ram... Delete what you have, go back and re-start the tutorial from the beginning. I doubt that Mr Price is using that many vertices.